# Does Google allow to load its libraries on a headless browsers (PhantomJS)?

Tags: google-maps, phantomjs

Does Google allow to load its libraries on a headless browsers? I am running tests with PhantomJS but they are failing because it `Can't find the variable: google`, but if I run the tests in Chrome they all pass.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Google JavaScript libraries run<sup>1</sup> on PhantomJS. It's the way they come to PhantomJS that's troubling sometimes. Most web servers disabled support for SSL v3 because of the POODLE vulnerability, but PhantomJS <1.9.8 uses it as a default.

You either need to pass the `--ssl-protocol=tlsv1 --ignore-ssl-errors=true` commandline flags to PhantomJS when you run it or you can update to a newer version such as 1.9.8 or 2.0.0.

<sup><sup>1</sup> That's not exactly true, since PhantomJS 1.x also doesn't implement `Function.prototype.bind` which many web sites use and which might stop the execution of some JavaScript.</sup>